# bulk post_content update

Tags: plugins, query, wp-update-post

I need to replace all post_content in a particular tag/category to the desired one i have. is their a plugin to accomplish it or is their a query to finish this. Iam sick of doing this manually, is their a way to accomplish it.

Comment: Maybe if you explain what is the post_content's content... Is always the same? It's a string/text that you want to modify with regex or something? If is that so, you could do a query with the tag/category in scope, and wp_update_post() would do the magic.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I mean:

```
<?php 
$tochange = get_posts('numberposts=-1&post_type=any&category_name=category-name-you-want-to-change');
foreach($tochange as $post){
    setup_postdata($post);
        $contentchange = ''; /*here you do the magic, string replace or whathever you want to do*/
        $tochange = array();
        $tochange['ID'] = $post->ID;
        $tochange['post_content'] = $contentchange;
        $out = wp_update_post($tochange);
        unset($tochange);
    }
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
function update_post_do()
{
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query("UPDATE wp_posts p
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON (p.ID = tr.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
AND tt.taxonomy = 'your_category' AND tt.term_id
IN ( 1 )) SET p.post_content = 'your content'");
}
add_action('init','update_post_do'); 
?>
```

Mention the category, id and the content to update