# How to convert custom fields to content

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I have some custom post types and inside them I have some custom fields that I need to convert in post content.

Is this possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using something similar

```
<?php
//Post we need to update
$id = 37;

 $custom_field = get_post_meta( $id, 'custom_field_key', true );
// Update post 37
  $mg_post = array(
      'ID'           => $id,
      'post_content' => $custom_field,
  );

// Update the post into the database
  wp_update_post( $mg_post );

//Delete the custom field
delete_post_meta( $id, 'custom_field_key' );
?>
```

Hope you got the idea. Let me know what have you tried.

Comment: Your code does work, thanks! But I found a way to bulk the changes by consulting [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47153/how-to-batch-update-post-content-with-custom-post-meta-value/#answer-47164)